# The declared property issue in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

My xcode version is 4.2.
When I use property to generate getter/setter methods. 
Here is the code:

```
 @interface NewSolutionViewController : UIViewController
 @property(nonatomic, weak) NSString a;
```

There is no issue exist. However when I turn into basic data type

```
  @interface NewSolutionViewController : UIViewController
  @property(nonatomic, weak) int a;
```

My program crashed. Do you guys know the reason?

Comment: what does "weak" do? Is it different from "assign"?

Comment: Can you post the crash, please?  This potentially sounds like a bug in the compiler (note that futureelite7's answer is correct).  Most importantly, there better be a compiler warning that you are ignoring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A basic data type is not an object, and hence does not need to be declared weak.

Use

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int a;
```

to directly assign to the variable.

Comment: actually, assign and weak are almost same.

Comment: `weak` is an ownership qualifier and can only be used with a property of retainable object pointer type. See the [ARC compiler-writer reference](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property) for the gorey details.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that an `int` is not an `NSObject`.

---

Elaborating a bit...

`NSObject` is the root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies. Read up on Apple's [Objects, Classes, and Messaging](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html) tutorial.

`int` is a basic machine type. It doesn't have methods, like an object, so it doesn't respond to messages.

Comment: YES, if I use a struct, the program will also crashed. what's the difference between NSObject and int. How it works on OC?

Answer (score 0):

`int` doesn't respond to `retain` - you probably want to put an `assign` in the property declaration for that one.

Comment: weak is a new feature in xcode4.2. It's the same meaning with assign